# LWC to visual force Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

We had the New Button for Opportunity Visual force Override page so that opportunities could be created only from Contact (New button on Opp Related List where contact field is mandatory). It shows the recordtype selection page before proceeding to the form.

We now need to have a Add button on LWC component to create new Opportunities.

```
navigateToNewOpp() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
                actionName: 'new'
            }
        });
    }
```

How do I pass the contact values here and also have the recordtype selection.

I tried:

```
navigateToNewOpp() {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            contactId: this.conId
        });
        console.log('defaultValues:::'+defaultValues);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues : defaultValues,
            }
        });
    }
```

Using above, I cam not able to get to the recordtype selection page.
If I use useRecordTypeCheck, I am able to see the Recordtype selection page but it is not showing the overriden vf page - standard page is shown.

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="NewOppOverrideControllerExtension" lightningStylesheets="true" title="{!$Label.New_Opportunity_page_title}">
    <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(errMsg))}" severity="error">
        {!errMsg}
    </apex:pageMessage>


    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.New_Opportunity_Opportunity_Detail_header}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.New_Opportunity_Save_Opportunity_button}" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.New_Opportunity_Opportunity_Info_Section_Header}" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.New_Opp_Info}" var="f">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity[f]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" />
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.New_Opportunity_General_Info_Section_Header}" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.New_Opp_Gen_Info}" var="f">
                    <!--<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity[f]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/>-->
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity[f]}" rendered="{!NOT(f == 'StageName')}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```